# Problem using HC-12 graphical configuration utility, invalid responses

Tags: wireless

I'm trying to use this utility [first time] to config a pair of HC-12s to a different channel, as I already have the default address in use.  It's a very handy utility, though I can find almost no reference to it via Google.

I found reference to the command here:
http://www.thebackshed.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=8246&PN=1

When I use to change the channel, i get 5 error messages of the form:
invalid response(1), 
invalid response(3.2), 
invalid response(3.3), 
invalid response(3.4), 
invalid response(3.5)

I am running on Windows 10 x6, using a standard USB cable to an Uno.
The wiring config is as follows:
VCC to 5v, 
GND to GND, 
RXD to pin 4, 
TXD to pin 5, 
Set to pin 6

I've also tried connecting the Set pin to GND, as I don't know whether this is necessary or not.

The board also has an 1N4007 diode in series with the power line, and a 1000uf capacitor twixt 5v and GND.  Nothing else.

There is a sample program at:
http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/understanding-and-implementing-the-hc-12-wireless-transceiver-module/

that should accomplish the same function via use of line commands and I shall try that next.  However, the configuration utility is so handy that I would like to have it in my kit of useful tools.

Seeking:
Assistance with the graphical configuration utility by someone who knows more than I, or perhaps a better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 'SET' pin needs to be connected to ground to place (and keep) the HC-12 in setup mode. when this is done you should be able to click on the "check configuration" button and receive a popup response containing the device's current configuration.

if the popup response contains no configuration data then either the HC-12 is not in setup mode ('SET' pin not grounded), or the usb to serial bridge you are using is not working. check the bridge by disconnecting the HC-12 and shorting together TxD and RxD on the bridge. you can use any terminal emulator to check loopback is working.

feel free to join the backshed forums and ask further questions about the HC-12.

cheers,
robert rozee
(author of the HC-12 config utility)